# Calling a Windows DLL from PHP

Tags: php, windows, dll

I am trying to call function form a DLL using PHP.

Based on my research, I need to do the following first from the command line:

```
REGSVR32 MyDLL.dll
```

Then I can do something like:

```
<?php
    $my_dll = new COM(‘MyDLL.Functions’);
    $text_to_be_encryopted = ‘This needs to be encrypted.’;
    $output_text = $my_dll->EncryptString($text_to_be_encryopted);
    echo $output_text
?>
```

The problem is that I cannot get Windows to register the DLL. I am getting the following message:

The moduleMyDLL.dll may not be compatible with the version of windows that you're running. Check if the module is compatible with an x86 (32-bit) or x64(64bit) version of regsvr32.exe

I tried this on a Windows 32 as well as a Windows 64 system with the same results. Any ideas (or an alternative way to do this)>

Answer (score 0):

I know I've had problems with this on Windows 7. Try Start->cmd->(right click)Run as Administrator and then run the command. I've spent countless hours running command prompt normally and then realized that was the problem.

Comment: That's not the issue. I get the same message whether or not I'm an admin

Comment: What do you mean, "whether or not your an admin". I'm not talking about being logged in as an admin. I'm talking about running the command prompt with escalated privileges; by doing what I said. Did you try that?

Comment: I mean that I've already tried running it with enhanced privileges to no avail.